# Self created SearchBar does not properly work when using in a Form {}

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am currently working on a small app for learning purposes, in which I have now integrated a SearchBar:

```
struct SearchBar: View {
    @Binding var searchText: String
    @Binding var isScannerPresented: Bool
    var placeholder: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(placeholder, text: $searchText)
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
                .overlay(
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        if !searchText.isEmpty {
                            Button(action: {
                                searchText = ""
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            Button(action: {
                isScannerPresented = true
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "barcode")
                    .padding(10)
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isScannerPresented) {
                BarCodeScanner(isbn: Binding($searchText), foundBooks: .constant(nil))
            }
        }
        .background(Color.secondary.opacity(0.1))
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

The search bar has a button to call up a scanner, as well as a Clear button as soon as something has been written in the TextField. Everything works fine so far. But when I place the searchbar within a Form{}, the scanner opens every time together with the Clear button. Can anyone help me with the reason for this?

The SearchBar works fine, until I put into a Form { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably another SwiftUI bug.
In your `SearchBar`, try adding `.buttonStyle(.plain)` to your `Buttons` or at least one of them. Or to your `SearchBar`, or to the `Form`, such as:

```
Form {
    SearchBar(searchText: $searchText,
              isScannerPresented: $isScannerPresented,
              placeholder: "search")
}
 .buttonStyle(.plain)  // <--- here
```

Note, unrelated, but you probably should use:

```
BarCodeScanner(isbn: $searchText, foundBooks: nil)
```